# When can a sequence be substituted for its limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I'm new to proof-writing in Real Analysis, and came across the following problem:

**Prove $\lim(a_nb_n)=\lim(a)\lim(b)$**. **Let $\lim(a), \lim(b)$ exist and $\lim(a)=L_a, \lim(b)=L_b$**

The first thing I was tempted to do was the following manipulation...

$$|a_nb_n-L_aL_b|=\left|a_n\left(b_n-\frac{L_aL_b}{a_n}\right)\right|\asymp L_a|b_n-L_b|$$
...from which point the rest of the proof is trivial. However, this immediately feels like an invalid simplification—the limit proofs I've encountered so far never use direct substitution of another limit. When is this type of manipulation appropriate in proofs?

Comment: Well, the claim you are trying to prove is one of the claims that sometimes justifies such a substitution. So regardless of when this type of manipulation is appropriate *in general*, I would avoid doing it *here*, to avoid circular reasoning.

Comment: You need to use the definition for $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ to show that the definition also holds for $a_nb_n\to ab$. In general we need to distinguish also the proof for $a,b$ real or infinity.

Comment: Oh, I can see the circularity in it now...thanks! In general, though, it's valid whenever the individual limits exist (and we've already proven how the limit functions over algebraic operations), right?